# How do i update helm repo to the latest version

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am trying to update my helm repo to the latest version using the below command. The repo name is returned from `helm repo list`. My helm version is `v3.3.1`

```
helm repo update <repo name>
```

but instead i get the below.

```
Error: "helm repo update" accepts no arguments

Usage:  helm repo update [flags]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a newer version of Helm; the option you're looking for seems to have been added in Helm 3.7.0.  The [Helm 3.7.0 release notes](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.7.0) include:

> `helm repo update` now accepts an optional repository name

If you can't upgrade to a newer version of Helm, you can still run `helm repo update` with no additional arguments to update all repositories' data.